# Using AlertView Text Input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

How do I use the text that is input from the AlertView? In this example, I am using AlertView to input a phone number that is then stored in textfield.text (code below).  I want to use this data in another method contained in the same .m file.  How do I properly reference this input (phone number) data from within another method?

```
- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Capture the phone number input from the alert pop-up window. UIAlertView Delegate added to allow the OS trigger this method to read the data.

    if (alertView.tag == 12) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"phonenumber: %@", textfield.text);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need to do one of two things.  The first option is to setup an ivar or property for your phone number in your class:

```
@implementation SomeViewController {
    NSString* _phoneNumber;
}

- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Capture the phone number input from the alert pop-up window. UIAlertView Delegate added to allow the OS trigger this method to read the data.

    if (alertView.tag == 12) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            _phoneNumber = textField.text;
        }
    }
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {
    NSLog(@"phonenumber: %@", _phoneNumber);
}
@end
```

Alternatively, you could make your other method take the phone number text as a parameter:

```
- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Capture the phone number input from the alert pop-up window. UIAlertView Delegate added to allow the OS trigger this method to read the data.

    if (alertView.tag == 12) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            [self someOtherMethodThatHandlesAPhoneNumber:textField.text];
        }
    }
}

- (void)someOtherMethodThatHandlesAPhoneNumber:(NSString*)phoneNumber {
    NSLog(@"phonenumber: %@", phoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: Works great, I used the first option.  Thx!